# Of Vegetables that are spiralized how would you sort them from easy to difficult end of spectrum to Spiralize?

Tags: vegetables

Of Vegetables that are spiralized how would you sort them from easy to difficult end of spectrum to Spiralize?

Which veggies do you find most difficult to spiralize? Even with a counter top Spiralizer?

- It could be because of the vegetables hardness & inability of sharpness/ Blades to cut correctly
- It could be because of vegetable fiber being too strong or too weak causing the spiral/ pieces to fall apart or disintegrate or liquefy/ juice up too much
- Whatever other factors play into the process of Spiralizing veggies?
- **What makes vegetables suitable for spiralization? (Easier and/ or more difficult? with examples?)**

**Note:** It's absurd to talk about spiralizing things that dont have typical structure for doing so. e.g. Peas, Cherry Tomatoes. Let's not go to such absurd areas.

PS: Size & structure that fits a spiralizer well or a typically spiralizable.

**Why am I asking? I've never spiralized before.**

I've been reading various articles, books, reviews on spiralization and spiralizors and some mentioned Zucchini are easy, some kind of Squash and Sweet Potatoes are hard etc etc.

These are all over the place and variable. If someone people here are regular executions of Spiralizing then they could chime in and share their easy vs difficult spectrums and it would be more trustable.

Yes some answers may differ a little bit but the spectrum from easy to difficult will largely have some consistency / bindings.
e.g. A carrot may not suddenly become easiest or softest as per someone.

Comment: Are you facing a problem spiralizing specific vegetables or types of vegetables? As written, this seems to me to just be soliciting individual complaints rather than seeking a single answer.

Comment: @Stephie - Now I've updated for it to mean both.. Could be difficult due to hardness or other reasons.

Comment: I removed your invite to make this into a "mini wiki". Years of experience have shown that this does not work well on the SE platform. The question is already borderline, with a high risk of ending up as an opinion poll - I hope the answerers will have enough awareness to not let that happen. Requesting even more formats makes it more difficult to keep it within the acceptable limits for an SE question.

Comment: What is the motivation for your question? It seems quite opinion-based and the potential answers not very useful. Brocolli is hard to spiralize, but what are you going to do with such information?

Comment: @JohnEye - Are you going to spiralize peas? Unlikely. It's assumed that these are vegetables that are typically spiralized because of their structure; and are on the difficult end of spectrum, versus some that are on easier end of spectrum.

Comment: @AlexS Sure, I understand that, but why are you asking the question? What value will the answers provide to you?

Comment: Poster may be inventing a new type spiralizer and wanting to demonstrate its advantages.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to ask if you're considering buying a spiralizer, though in that case I would suggest framing as what it can and can't do, and including the range in between from easy to difficult.

Comment: Broccoli stem might actually spiralize real well :)

Comment: @JohnEye - As someone who has never spiralized is it not a valid question to ask from people who have experience doing so?

Comment: @LorelC. - Yes, such information would be beneficial for anyone interesting in devising better spiralizers.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yes, under such a scenario it would help to know for someone to go about looking at Spiralizers as well as "ranges of veggies" from Easy to Difficult. How do I do this - "suggest framing as what it can and can't do, and including the range in between from easy to difficult." Please feel free to add to question/ update it..

Comment: A suggestion: please take any meta content (e.g. why you feel this question is valid, how it compares to other questions) to the [meta] portion of the site. Let your question stay focused on what you really want to know, about spiralizing :)

Comment: @Erica - Look at the number of off track comments and questions ^ peas and so on. Why do I wish to spiralize? To cook and eat.

Comment: I understand the way the site works can be complicated, but everybody is trying to help you formulate this question in as best a way as possible to reach that answer. Discussing that is what [meta] is for, so _your question_ can be what's the focus of this page rather than _a conversation about your question_ (which is what the comments have become!). Again, it is a suggestion, not a criticism or insult.

Comment: @AlexS: Well, if I was in your shoes, I would probably ask something like "What makes vegetables suitable for spiralization". Then the answers would be general enough for a reader to be able to apply the advice to any of the hundreds of kinds of vegetable in the world.

Comment: @JohnEye - I've mentioned that in my question - Hardness, Fibrousness etc. and even if I changed the question to your title, these are not Metals or Polymers that they'd be able to give "physics like" attributes to the Range of them.

Answer (score 3):

Lotus root must have evolved under the constant threat of spiralizing animals, it is perfect at frustrating spiralization: extremely brittle, and having large cavities that would interrupt any spiral.

Apart from that: anything that simply does not come in a size that fits a spiralizer well (green beans, thin asparagus) or without a lot of prep (hokkaido pumpkin, winter melon). Or anything that is too soft and tough to cleanly be cut with an unsharpenable blade like found in a spiralizer, eg mushrooms, tomatoes, citrus fruit or eggplants.

Comment: I've heard that the center of the vegetable is also important .... you can spiralize a young zucchini, but older ones are too mushy in the middle that the style where you spear it onto a post don't work.  (the ones that are like a giant pencil sharpener might be okay)

Comment: Overstored zucchini can be rather woody/pithy in the middle, too ...